# My Java code always give false value but my API got it true?

Tags: java

I have problem with my code.

Here is a pic

[image]

The result is always `false`.

but in my API

[image]

both results are `true`.

Here part of my **Java** code. Any help?

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("in.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("result.txt"), true);     
        String User;

        while ((User = br.readLine()) != null){
            URL url = new URL("http://mysecretweb.com/r/migrate.php?name="+User);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));

            boolean result = Boolean.valueOf(reader.readLine());
            String str = Boolean.toString(result);
            System.out.println(User+" is "+str);
            out.write(User+" is "+str);
            out.write("\r\n");               
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: I don't know what you exactly want to hear, but what are you trying to do ? Reading a file is false ? Then maybe your path is different in your "API"

Comment: Where do you print the result?

Comment: Everything is ok. The path is right. But when i try to run my code, it always "false". I think something wrong with the Boolean on my code?

Comment: @ÉlLäwlíèt where do you print your boolean result?

Comment: Instead of passing `reader.readLine()` directly to `Boolean.valueOf()`, why don't you put it in a `String` variable, print it out, and then pass it to `Boolean.valueOf()`? It might help you to see where the problem is. It's also easier to work with a debugger like that. And please add the results of this research to the question, as *text* (you can format it as code), not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Dump the raw result of the call with java. **Boolean.valueOf( value )** is true only if the first line you are reading is parseable as "true"

If the line contains other characters like web headers or is an html page or the content has spaces... it can't be parseable.

Example of code (realy simple and bogus,but functional) to dump result and text how many lines have. and if it has spaces.

```
public class StackTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String userToTest="something";
        URL url = new URL("http://mysecretweb.com/r/migrate.php?name=" + userToTest);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        do{
            line = reader.readLine();
            System.out.print("|");
            System.out.print(line);
            System.out.println("|");
        }while(line!=null);
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your code is work, but it only checking 1 name "something" etc. I don't understand **Java** at all. can you make it work like my code? Like, checking every name on `input.txt` ? (err, maybe you can help me on skype or email, ah nvm)

Comment: The code helps you to view the content of the web call the web is returning only "true"

Comment: http://gagqga.gq/r/migrate.php?name=12eqweqwrc <- this name is "false" because its not registered.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());` instead of `BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader ( connection.getInputStream()))`, then you will get your desird output.

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("in.txt"));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("result.txt"), true);

        String user;

        while ((user = br.readLine()) != null){

            URL url = new URL("http://gagqga.gq/r/migrate.php?name="+user);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            InputStreamReader reader=new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());

            boolean result = Boolean.valueOf(reader.ready());

            String str = Boolean.toString(result);
            System.out.println(user+" is "+str);
            out.write(user+" is "+str);
            out.write("\r\n");     

           }

       }  

   }
```